# How can i active multi keybored in as3

Tags: actionscript-3, flash

I am making a running game where hero will run, face obstacle and proceed the obstacle with jump and slide.

now the hero will run when user press D and it will keep running until a fixed point but the problem is once hero start running the other to button `W = jump` and `S = slide` is not working.

i want this 2 button to work while hero is running .

here is my code

```
import flash.display.Stage;
import flash.events.KeyboardEvent;
import flash.ui.Keyboard;
import flash.display.MovieClip;
import flash.events.Event;

kim.gotoAndStop("hero Stand");

var dPressed:Boolean = false;
var aPressed:Boolean = false;
var jumping:Boolean = false;
var sPressed:Boolean = false;

stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_DOWN , keyDownHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(KeyboardEvent.KEY_UP , KeyUpHandaler);
stage.addEventListener(Event.ENTER_FRAME , gameLoop);

function keyDownHandaler(Devent:KeyboardEvent):void
{
        if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.D )
            {
                dPressed = true;
            }

        else if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.S && !jumping && !sPressed)
            {
                sPressed = true;
            }
        else if (Devent.keyCode == Keyboard.W && !jumping && !sPressed)
            {
                jumping = true;
            }

function KeyUpHandaler (Uevent:KeyboardEvent):void 
{
    if (Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.D)
        {
            //dPressed = false; (i commented this so that hero don't stop running)
            //hero.gotoAndStop("hero Stand");
        }

    else if(Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.W)
    {
            jumping = false; 
            hero.gotoAndStop("heroStand");
    }

    else if(Uevent.keyCode == Keyboard.S)
    {
            sPressed = false;
            hero.gotoAndStop("hero Stand");
    }
}

function gameLoop(Levent:Event):void
{
    if (dPressed)
         {
        hero.x += 10;   
        hero.gotoAndStop("hero Run");
        }

    else if(jumping)
        {
             hero.y -= 15;
            hero.x += 10;
            hero.gotoAndStop("hero Jump");
        }

    else if(sPressed) {

            hero.x += 10;
            hero.gotoAndStop("hero Slide");
            }   
    }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Because you are using `else if` statements. Instead, just use separate `if`statements. AS3 will read through an `else if` logical block only as far as it needs to in order to find a true condition, at which point it carries out that bit of code and then exits to the end of the `else if` statement, *skipping everything after it.* If you want all conditions to be tested (is he running? Is he jumping? is he sliding?) regardless of the state of the other key presses, then just use `if`statements. Use `else if` only when you want to reserve code to be run *only if the previous condition were false.*

**In your case** i would imagine you only would want the player to be able to slide if he is running but *not* jumping, right?  So that could look like this:

```
If (dPressed) {
    hero.x += 10;
    hero.goToAndPlay("hero run");
}
If (jumping) { // this code will run regardless of if dPressed is true
    hero.y -= 15;
}
else if (sPressed) { // this code will only be read if jumping is not true (you can't jump and slide at the same time)
    hero.goToAndStop("hero slide");
}
```

You'd have to alter your other logical statements likewise.

I wouldn't use any `else` statements in the keyboard event handler section. Better in my opinion to have AS3 simply always check the state of the keys being pressed... deal with the logic in the  `gameLoop` function.

Comment: thanks for answering but the problem is in your method my movie-Clip of jumping or sliding is not playing , i have 7 frame jump animation and 5 frame slide animation which is not playing hero.gotoAndStop("hero Jump"); and hero.gotoAndStop("hero Slide"); , it just go to the first frame and stay like that and after end it goes back to run. any idea what is the problem??

Comment: use goToAndPlay not goToAndStop

Comment: That is a completely different issue from the question you asked. Keep focused on one issue per post. Your question was not about playing movie clips. Your question was about getting two key presses recognized. If my solution worked, mark it as such. With my suggestion are you now able to make the hero jump or slide while running? (again, if the movie clips aren't playing, that's a separate issue and you should ask that in a separate post).